# Alternatives to using double loops with different length of pairwise iterations in list in R programming

Tags: r, loops, vectorization, lapply, mapply

I am trying to evaluate the intersection between a series of non-redundant element pairs from the list with length 10 (e.g. "abc"), which, for each element, contains two integer vectors with length 20, and generate the vector for the pair indices for the intersection that has more than a certain number (e.g. 2), as shown below:

```
set.seed(42)
abc <- replicate(10, list(sample(1:100, 20), sample(1:100, 20)), simplify=F)

edges <- c()
for (i in 1:(length(abc)-1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):length(abc)) {
    if (length(intersect(abc[[i]][[1]], abc[[j]][[1]])) >= 2 & length(intersect(abc[[i]][[2]], abc[[j]][[2]])) >= 2) {
      edges <- c(edges, c(i,j))
    }
  }
}
```

I am just wondering if there is any other way to produce the same result but in a more efficient and faster way? Using loops for the list with a reasonable size seems okay, but when it comes to a larger list, it takes more time than expected. I was trying to use 'lapply' or other similar functions, but using those 'lapply' typed functions seems straightforward for single loops, but for double loops with different numbers of loop iterations, it is hard for me to come up with a good solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you need in reality? Is it important that you need intersect?  Are the integer vectors indeed have values 1..100 ? What is the size of your lists?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `combs` to generate indices across which you can iterate:

```r
set.seed(47)

abc <- replicate(10, list(sample(1:100, 20), sample(1:100, 20)), simplify=F)

combs <- combn(length(abc), 2)

i <- apply(combs, 2, function(x){
    length(intersect(abc[[x[1]]][[1]], abc[[x[2]]][[1]])) >= 2 &
    length(intersect(abc[[x[1]]][[2]], abc[[x[2]]][[2]])) >= 2
})

combs[,i]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     2     2     2     2
#> [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10     3     4     5     6
#>      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24]
#> [1,]     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     4
#> [2,]     7     8    10     4     6     8     9    10     5     6     7
#>      [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35]
#> [1,]     4     4     4     5     5     5     5     5     6     6     6
#> [2,]     8     9    10     6     7     8     9    10     7     8     9
#>      [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41]
#> [1,]     6     7     7     7     8     9
#> [2,]    10     8     9    10    10    10
```

Note, however, that because combinations get big quickly, while this is fast for 10 elements (`choose(10, 2)` = 45 combinations), for a not-unimaginable list of 10,000 elements, checking `choose(10000, 2)` = 49,995,000 combinations with two subelements each will take a lot more memory and time.